# Please tell me if it is possible to use the youtube api to get statistics of subscribers by gender, age, country?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Hello everyone Please tell me if it is possible to use the youtube api to get statistics of subscribers by gender, age, country? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why don't you check out the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/dimensions)?

Answer (score 2):

You cant get any information about subscribers via the YouTube data api.

even channel.list does not return a list of who has subscribed.

subscriptions.list lists what the current authenticated user has subscribed to.

There is no endpoint that will return who has subscribed to a channel. Let alone give you age and gender information.